# Apache default configuration not being overridden by virtual host

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

Upgrading to a new server - didn't have this problem with Ubuntu 18.04LTS, new server is 20.04LTS

I was having problems with the sites internal pages not working (not respecting the .htaccess file) so I changed apache2.conf - it USED to have AllowOverride none and the vhost wouldn't override it and still isn't... If I change what I have now where the vhost has "allowoverride none" it still allows overriding per the apache2.conf file.

My old servers never did this - I was able to set this on a per-site basis with the vhosts. The old server has the same apache2.conf with AllowOverride none set.

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf file has this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The virtualhost looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
    
    <Directory "/var/www/mysite">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand your description of the problem. Please explain what exactly is going wrong now - nevermind what was happening before.